# Text-based adventure survival horror game

Tags: c++, adventure-game

This is the first couple lines of my new (will be) 8-bit co-op horror game. This is just the code for the first player text-based adventure storyline for the console game.  Please critique.

```
//Andrew Tew
/*
First EVER Co-Op Horror Game!
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Declared Variables
string Answer;





//Title Screen and Custom Letter Output
system ("title Until Death We Part");
system ("color 0f");
system ("mode 1000");
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t'------------------------------'\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|------------------------------|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|--------The first ever--------|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|----8-bit Horror Game Co-Op---|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|--------Survival Game---------|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|--------By: Andrew Tew--------|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|\"The Backstory/Text Adventure\"|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|------------------------------|\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t'------------------------------'\n";
cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tPlay in Full Screen Mode/Maximized Mode for the Best Experience!\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";



/*End Start Screen

Begin Help Screen (Refrain from using Gotos)*/

system ("pause");
system ("cls");

cout << "\tHELP SCREEN:\n";
cout << "\t-----------\n\n\n";
cout << "\tAnswers:\n";
cout << "\tyes (ALWAYS LOWERCASE)\n";
cout << "\tno (ALWAYS LOWERCASE)\n\n";
cout << "\tWHO ARE YOU:\n";
cout << "\tPOSSIBLE ETHNICITIES(ALWAYS LOWERCASE):\n";
cout << "\twhite\n";
cout << "\tblack\n";
cout << "\tasian\n";
cout << "\tlatino\n\n";
cout << "\tPOSSIBLE HAIR COLORS(ALWAYS LOWERCASE):\n";
cout << "\tblond (male)\n";
cout << "\tblonde (female)\n";
cout << "\tbrown\n";
cout << "\tblack\n";
cout << "\twhite\n";
cout << "\tgray\n\n\n\n\n\n";
cout << "Cont. Next Page\n";

system ("pause");//Next Page Help Screen
system ("cls");

cout << "\n\n\tPOSSIBLE GENDERS(ALWAYS LOWERCASE):\n";
cout << "\tmale\n";
cout << "\tfemale\n";
cout << "\tit\n\n";
cout << "\tPOSSIBLE EYE COLORS(ALWAYS LOWERCASE):\n";
cout << "\tblue\n";
cout << "\tbrown\n";
cout << "\tgreen\n";
cout << "\tgray\n\n";
cout << "\tNAME LIMITS AND MINIMUMS:\n";
cout << "\tNames must contain at LEAST 3 letters.\n";
cout << "\tNames must contain at MOST 10 letters.\n";
cout << "\tNames must NOT contain spaces.\n\n\n\n\n\n";

system ("pause");
system ("cls");

cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tTinyBit Games Presents to you:\n";
cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t           Torn\n";
/*
In the future code a "Load" Option and a "New Game" Option
Also code a "Save" option that can be done at any time
Remember this is a TEXT ADVENTURE not any other game
*/


system ("pause");//Game Begins Here Still Refrain from goto statements
system ("cls");

One:
cout << "\tIt's Dark... Pitch Black. A throbbing headache bursts into the front of your head.\n";
cout << "As you begin to get up from where you are you realize that you are bound by strong\n";
cout << "rope.\n\n";
cin >> Answer;
if (Answer == "wait"){
    cout << "You wait... the time is unknown\n\n";
}else {
    cout << "\n\n\nThat answer is not a usable answer in this situation\n\n\n";
    goto One; //I didn't know what else to use please critique!
}
cout << "\tYou hear footsteps faintly, distant but audible. They are getting louder and they\n";
cout << "suddenly stop. A door creaks open and you hear it touch a wall\n\n\n";

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a little biased, but I'd highly recommend that you check out my library for creating text-based adventure games, [Cactus](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom/CactusReborn). It's written in Python, but it shouldn't be to difficult to translate.

Comment: @EthanBierlein I downloaded your file, but I don't know how to install the python language and I'm not sure what translates to what and I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: You need to add Cactus to your `PYTHONPATH` so it's importable. You can then either install [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) or the Python tools for Visual Studio.

Comment: If you're looking for a system other than C, you should know that players like well established systems over homebrew parsers. You should look into [Inform 7](http://inform7.com).

Answer (score 7):

I see you've ignored the advice from your previous question. To avoid duplication, I'm going to quote them:

From [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106954/22222):

> **Goto**
>
> At a first approximation, never use `goto`. It makes it more or less
>   impossible to follow code. Without `goto`, you also don't need labels.
>   Instead, just call different functions. Or keep an internal state
>   machine. Or really any possible other solution. Code with `goto` like
>   this is incredibly brittle - what if you want to add more states
>   somewhere in between? Good luck keeping track of everything.

From [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106953/22222):

> There many things here that can be improved. First off, let's tackle
>   some best practices. Generally, doing stuff like this with `system`
>   isn't very good:
>
> > ```
> > system("pause");
> > system("cls");
> > ```
>
> To start off, `system("pause");` is a bad way of *"pausing"* for user
>   input. First off, there's a decently sized overhead just to execute a
>   shell command, and doing this is rather insecure. If you really need
>   to pause on user input, and ignore it, then just do something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> std::cin.get();
> ```
>
> Secondly, putting anything like this at the top of your file is a bad
>   idea:
>
> > ```
> > using namespace std;
> > ```
>
> This pollutes your local namespace with *everything* in `std`, and it
>   can lead to some name conflicts, especially if you're using a library
>   like `boost`. There's a good reason it's named `std` and not
>   `standard`. It's easier to prefix everything with `std::` rather than
>   `standard::`.

Now for some advice specific to this question:

First, all the newlines and tabs are quite noisy. You can consider putting it in a variable:

```
std::string tab(6, '\t');
std::cout << tab << "...";
```

Secondly, instead of your `goto` approach, it's more likely that you want a `while` loop instead. Some users insist that the `while` loop is a glorified `goto`, but without the negatives.

```
std::string answer;
while (std::cin >> answer)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! The suggestion on creating a variable for tab was great! Could you please clarify the loop answer in a "cout" coding fashion? I'm not great with std:: etc.